# Solve matrix equation with given matrices A and B

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

can anyone help me with this :) ?

> Solve matrix equation: $(A-I)(X+I)B^T = 6B$ where:
>
> $$ A= \begin{bmatrix}
>          3 & 2 \\
>          5 & 3 \\
>          \end{bmatrix}
> $$ 
>   $$ B= \begin{bmatrix}
>         3 & 2 \\
>         7 & 5 \\
>         \end{bmatrix}
> $$
>   where $B^T$ is transposition of $B$

Answer (score 5):

$X=(A-I)^{-1} \times 6B \times (B^T)^{-1}-I$

Answer (score 2):

$$(A-I)(X+I)B^T = 6B$$
Note that $B$ and $B^T$ are square matrices with determinant non-zero ($1$) and hence are invertible.

So, $$(A-I)(X+I) = 6B{\left(B^T\right)}^{-1}$$
$$(A-I)X + (A-I) = 6B{\left(B^T\right)}^{-1}$$
$$(A-I)X=I-A+6B{\left(B^T\right)}^{-1}$$

Since $A-I$ is also invertible, 
$$X = (A-I)^{-1}\left(I-A+6B{\left(B^T\right)}^{-1}\right)$$
$$= -I+6(A-I)^{-1}B{\left(B^T\right)}^{-1}$$

Answer (score 0):

This is a system of $4$ linear equations in the variables $x_1,\ldots ,x_4$ of $X$, which has a unique solution, namely
$$
X=\begin{pmatrix} 27 & -38 \cr 5 & -8\end{pmatrix}.
$$
So it is only solving $4$ linear equations in $4$ unknowns.

Comment: Could you expand your thought?

Comment: There is nothing to expand. Write $X$ with $4$ unknowns $x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4$ and write down the matrix equation. This gives four linear equations, one for each coefficient. Then solve it, say, with Gauss elimination.